# this.file.listDir won't return folders under the applicationStorageDirectory

Tags: cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native, cordova-plugin-file

when I am trying to list my folder directory with ionic-native file i am not getting any folders in result.

My Code:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.filesystem.listDir(this.filesystem.applicationStorageDirectory, '').then((result) => {
       console.log(result);
        /*result will have an array of file objects with 
        file details or if its a directory*/
        for (let file of result) {
          if (file.isDirectory == true && file.name != '.' && file.name != '..') {
            console.log("This is a folder");
            // Code if its a folder
          } else if (file.isFile == true) {
            // Code if its a file
            console.log("This is a file");
            let name = file.name // File name
            console.log("file name: " + name);
           // let path = file.path // File path
            file.getMetadata(function (metadata) {
              let size = metadata.size; // Get file size
            })
          }
        }
     });
    });
```

I am using:     "@ionic-native/file": "4.12.0",
With imports:
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not passed the directory name in `this.filesystem.listDir(this.filesystem.applicationStorageDirectory, '')` you have to pass directory name in this method. You can get directory name from the `this.filesystem.applicationStorageDirectory`. First alert `this.filesystem.applicationStorageDirectory` and check which type of path you get.

If path is like :

> file:///storage/emulator/0/somefolder

then get the directory name as following :

```
let appStorageDir = "file:///storage/emulator/0/somefolder";
let dirName = appStorageDir.substring(appStorageDir.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

If there is slash(/) in the last of path like :

> file:///storage/emulator/0/somefolder/

then get the directory name as following :

```
let appStorageDir = "file:///storage/emulator/0/somefolder/";
appStorageDir = appStorageDir.substring(0,appStorageDir.lastIndexOf("/"));
let dirName = appStorageDir.substring(appStorageDir.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Now pass that dirName in method as following :

```
this.filesystem.listDir(this.filesystem.applicationStorageDirectory, dirName)
```

Hope it will help you !!!